# Is it ok to use 14-3 wire to connect fan and recessed light

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

We have pre wiring for fan. It's 14-3 wire - white, black, red and ground. The black wire has constant power and I am using it to run the ceiling fan. I have to use remote to turn the fan/light on and off. I capped the red wire which is controlled by the switch.

My question is: can I use the red, white and ground to add some recessed light?

I am just worried because I am using the black to run the fan. I'm not sure if I can use the same neutral and ground for recessed lights which is already being used for the fan.

Comment: Somewhere along the line, this circuit probably also supplies power to an outlet. You've probably plugged your vacuum cleaner into it while the light was on. Your house is full of circuits that supply a variety of different loads, a ceiling fan & ceiling lights are no different.

Comment: Does the room have a switch in the usual location *that operates a light*, or have you defeated that?  Because the building codes requires one (1) light switch in the usual location to actually control a light.  That is to protect the safety of guests, particularly first responders.

Comment: The black wire has constant power and its connected to the fan. I am using the remote to control the fan as well as the light that is with the fan. This fan doesn't control by any switch. i have 2 switches. One switch controls one of the outlet on the wall (half outlet), the other switch controls the red wire which in pre wiring for fan. We are good with fan Since its working fine with black, white and ground.Only wire left is the red one, which is tapped up for now. i want to use this red wire, white and ground to connect some recessed lights,so it can be control by the second switch

Comment: This second switch only controls the pre wiring (red,white, and ground) and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

You can share neutral for devices that are all powered on the same cable. (after which can split off the live and tap the neutral in a 14-2 cable to power the new lamps

So yes it's good.

14 gauge is acceptable if **the breaker for that circuit is 15A or smaller**.

Comment: Emphasized the critical part. Don't know about the "or smaller", though. I personally haven't seen breakers smaller than 15a. Maybe they exist somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. The black wire has constant power and its connected to the fan. I am using the remote to control the fan as well as the light that is with the fan. This fan doesn't control by any switch.
i have 2 switches. One switch controls one of the outlet on the wall (half outlet), the other switch controls the red wire which in pre wiring for fan. We are good with fan Since its working fine with black, white and ground.Only wire left is the red one, which is tapped up for now. i want to use this red wire, white and ground to connect some recessed lights,so it can be control by the second switch

Comment: This second switch only controls the pre wiring (red,white, and ground) and nothing else.